# Object to List<myObject> in java

Tags: java, casting

I have a method that returns an Object type with reference data. This Object can be a single instance of ClassA or a list of instances of ClassB.

If it is a single instance of ClassA, I can easily cast it as follows:

```
(ClassA) data
```

Now, I am stuck with the second case, because in the second case, Object is indeed a `List<ClassB>`, how can I cast Object data into `List<ClassB>` dataList?

```
Object data ----> List<ClassB>
```

Thank you

Comment: "This Object can be a single instance of ClassA or a list of instances of ClassB" Why? This sounds like an incredibly bad design pattern, what are you _actually_ doing, with real class names and a description of the task you're trying to fulfill for which you've written this code.

Comment: I totally agree this is a horrible design. However, this is a training project that I have to deliver the functionalities and despite how horrible design this may seem, the class that returns an Object which may be any of several things is really helping the overall project design. This is an mvc web development and the specific tech stack is not as elaborate or advanced as you may think.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `instanceof` to check the type of the object

If you're using [java-16](/questions/tagged/java-16)

```java
if (data instanceof ClassA singleObject) {
    // do something with singleObject
} else if (data instanceof List list) {
    // do something with list
}
```

Otherwise

```
if (data instanceof ClassA) {
    ClassA singleObject = (ClassA) data;
    // do something with singleObject
} else if (data instanceof List) {
    List<ClassB> list = (List<ClassB>) data;
    // do something with list
}
```

Note that you'll get a compiler warning because you're making an unchecked assignment. You can use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on the method to make it go away

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to do it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = new ArrayList<Object>();
        List<Object> l = (List<Object>) o;
    }

}
```